# Why does vowel length of Middle English trust not match its probable Old Norse etymon traust?

Tags: etymology, middle-english

It's natural to expect retention of vowel length when a word is borrowed from ON to ME, and that's indeed what happened with e. g. ME adj. [*lọ̄s*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED26114) 'free; loose' from ON *lauss*.

However, ME n. *trust* [is stated to probably derive](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED47298) from ON *traust*, which doesn't correspond to that pattern. What might have happened here?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems to me that the vowel sounds are among the first things to be mangled when a word is "adopted" from another language.

Comment: "It's natural to expect retention of vowel length when a word is borrowed from ON to ME"— is it, though? As that assertion is the very foundation of your question, what research are you basing it on? I ask because I find it highly unlikely anyone can possibly know that since there are no audio recordings of ON or ME being spoken and there's no way for anyone alive to know that since everyone that anyone alive could ever hear natively speak ON and ME in order to know that died hundreds of years before they were born.

Comment: The source you cite in the Middle English Compendium doesn't actually say it derives from Old Norse *traust*: it says "Prob. ON (cp. OI *traust* & Dan. *trøst*, Swed. *tröst*)" So they think it probably comes from Old Norse, but don't specify a form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most probable origin is actually the reflex<sup>1</sup> of an unattested Old English word or a zero-grade<sup>2</sup> derivation from a Proto-Germanic root. It appears to be phonologically impossible to get it from Norse. *OED* provides the etymology of *trust* (*n.*), the Middle English forms of the word, the additional information about the vowel mismatch from early Scandinavian words and the alternate spellings as below:

> **Forms:** 
> α. Middle English–1600s **truste**, Middle English– **trust**. 
> β. Middle English–1600s **trost**, Middle English **troste**.
>
> **Origin:** Probably a word inherited from Germanic. 
> **Etymology:** Probably the reflex of an unattested Old English **trust* (perhaps cognate with Middle High German *getrüste* company, troop, and the Frankish etymon of post-classical Latin *trustis* retinue, bodyguard (c800 in the *Lex Salica*)) < the Germanic base of trust *adj.*
>
> *Alternative etymology.*
>
> As with trust *v.* and trust *adj.*, semantic correspondence with related nouns in North Germanic languages has led to a view that this word is a borrowing from early Scandinavian; however, this presents phonological difficulties and does not easily account for the vowel of the α. forms. For further discussion, see R. Dance in *Eng. Stud.* 81 (2000) 377.
>
> *Form history.*
>
> The β. forms probably at least partly reflect association with related nouns in early Scandinavian, although they may also reflect the Middle English spelling convention of writing *o* for *u*.

*OED* mentions another reference in the alternate etymology above by Richard Dance, a professor of Early English in St Catherine's College, Cambridge. I've searched the reference and found an explanation in one of his works where he mentions that it is relatively rare to see a secure evidence for Old English descent of a form first attested in Middle English; but usually dismissed as borrowings from Norse are considered more exciting and favored. He compares this allure of the Scandinavian element to the phenomenon *Nornomania*<sup>3</sup>, the alleged obsession with the Scandinavian (‘Norn’) heritage in research on the dialects of Orkney and Shetland. He adds that *trust* cannot be a loan from Old Norse and explains the origin of *trust* as below with some additional references:

> A classic example is PDE *trust*, which it is now usually agreed cannot be explained as a loan from ON (cp. OIcel *traustr* ‘trusty’, treysta ‘to make trusty, trust’) but must be referred to a zero-grade derivation on the same PGmc root, which happens not to be recorded in OE; see e.g. *OED* s.v. *trust* adj., d’Ardenne (1961: glossary s.v. *trusten*), Hoad (1985: 139–40).
>
> <sub>Dance, Richard, 'Getting a word in: Contact, etymology and English vocabulary in the twelfth century', in Janet Carsten, and Simon Frith (eds), British Academy Lectures 2013-14, British Academy Lectures (London, 2015; online edn, British Academy Scholarship Online, 21 Jan. 2016), https://doi.org/10.5871/bacad/9780197265864.003.0007</sub>

<sub>Abbreviations in the above citation: 

PDE: Present Day English 

ON: Old Norse (used to refer to any Scandinavian language variety down to about 1500 AD.) 

OIcel: Old Icelandic 

PGmc: Proto-Germanic 

OE: Old English</sub>

---

<sub>1. reflex: *(linguistics)* The descendant of an earlier language element, such as a word or phoneme, in a daughter language. - *[*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reflex)*</sub>

<sub>2. zero-grade: *(Indo-European linguistics)* In Proto-Indo-European linguistics, an ablaut form of a root characterized by the absence of the basic ablauting vowel phonemes */e/ and */o/. 

*bʰr̥- is the zero-grade of the Indo-European root *bʰer- meaning “to carry, bear”. - *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zero-grade)*</sub>

<sub>3. Citation from: 

Gunnel Melchers | University of Stockholm 

https://doi.org/10.1075/cilt.321.11mel</sub>

Comment: I love the word *Nornomania*!

Comment: @tchrist _Nornomania_ is an interesting coinage and find indeed. _Norn_ refers to the The Norn language (the Orkney and Shetland Norn); however, it originally referred to a Norwegian or a Norse. _Norn_ is also connected to the Scandinavian mythology and it is the name of each of the three Fates or goddesses of destiny (usually in plural as _Nornir_ or _Norns_).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found a bit more detailed discussion with links to previous literature in Dance's other work published recently, "Words derived from Old Norse in Sir Gawain and the Green Knight: An etymological survey" (doi:10.1111/1467-968x.12148_02)